# What does “&&x” mean in this CPython code?

Tags: c++, cpython

What is this C++ Syntax:

```
static void *opcode_targets[256] = { 
    &&_unknown_opcode, 
    &&TARGET_POP_TOP,
    ...
    }
```

I found that in the [cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/opcode_targets.h)

Is it a function? Why `&&` is added at the beginning?

Comment: I appreciate that the top comment on the recommended answer is "Sure that is not C++ code??"

Comment: @NotAProgrammer - A typical occurrence between warring nations. Every weird thing that happens is the other people's fault :P